# More modern or more conventional version of Emacs

Tags: software-recommendation, emacs, text-editor

Is there a more modern or more conventional version of Emacs?

I'm thinking something like Aquamacs from Mac OS X. I'd like the standard conventional keyboard shortcuts found in common programs to work to work and more organized menus with modern naming conventions.

Really I'm just looking for an Aquamacs like Emacs for Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see it is more or less the initiative behind the [ErgoEmacs](http://ergoemacs.org). Though it is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323630/should-i-start-out-learning-emacs-with-ergoemacs) to start using Emacs with it.

Personally I'd recommend customize Emacs to fit Your needs step-by-step. No one really knows what You want Emacs to be. But Emacs allows almost any kind of configuration. You can cast each of Your requirenments to a separate stackexchange question -- Ask Ubuntu, StackOverflow or SuperUser -- depending on the feature.

Answer (score 1):

The “Use CUA keys” setting, available under the Options menu in GNU Emacs 24, provides at least the keyboard shortcuts part of what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/) where thought was put into a better and powerful user experience.

Answer (score -1):

Aquamacs is an Emacs clone for OS X, the [about page](http://aquamacs.org/about.shtml) makes it very clear:

> Aquamacs is an Aqua-native build of the powerful Emacs text editor. By
>   "Aqua-native," we mean more than just the fact that this version of
>   Emacs runs as a standard OS X application.  Aquamacs features
>   extensive customization: it will feel and behave mostly like an Aqua
>   program - while still being a real GNU Emacs with all the ergonomy and
>   extensibility you've come to expect from this world-class editor.
>
> [...] Aquamacs is a modern editor based on GNU Emacs that makes the
>   Mac user feel at home. For instance, in addition to traditional Emacs
>   shortcuts like C-x C-f (open a new file), Aquamacs understands
>   Command-O.

Meaning that the extra functionality provided by the Aquamacs build is specifically directed at OS X and will not function (or even make sense) on other systems.

Instead of an alternative you should simply go for the real thing - available from the Software Centre.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  OP wasn't asking for Aquamacs on Ubuntu, but rather for an analogous piece of software, providing some of the same (non-OS-specific) features.

Comment: And isn't Emacs "analogous" to Aquamacs?

Comment: Not in the way the question asks for: a version of Emacs, for Ubuntu, customised to have keybindings, windowing behaviour, etc following modern conventions rather than emacs conventions. These features make sense on any OS.